# Laravel + Mongo(Jessenger) Cannot create SSL client. SSL is not enabled in this build

Tags: laravel, mongodb, ssl

I am using laravel 5.8 and mongodb atlas cluster , however i am unable to connect my laravel to mongodb using jessenger package, its giving `"Cannot create SSL client. SSL is not enabled in this build"` error. However it works fine if i use mongodb installed at my localhost but not working at remote mongodb atlas.

However it works fine if i use mongodb compass for remote connection
Here is the output of php - i | grep -i openssl

```
    SSL Version => OpenSSL/1.0.2k
    openssl
    OpenSSL support => enabled
    OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
    OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
    Openssl default config => /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf
    openssl.cafile => no value => no value
    openssl.capath => no value => no value
    Native OpenSSL support => enabled
```

so i think ssl is enable for my php (V7.3)
here is the config of my db connection in laravel config

```
     'mongodb' => [
     'driver'   => 'mongodb',
     'dsn'=>'mongodb+srv://*********@*****-www.mongodb.net/*****?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
    'host'     => env('MONGO_DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port'     => env('MONGO_DB_PORT', 27017),
    'database' => env('MONGO_DB_DATABASE'),
    'options'  => []
     ],

    and my env file 
    MONGO_DB_HOST=******-wwfsdf.mongodb.net
    MONGO_DB_PORT=27017
    MONGO_DB_DATABASE=****
    MONGO_DB_USERNAME=****
    MONGO_DB_PASSWORD=****
```

my error that i receive is on calling any kind of api is

> "message": "Cannot create SSL client. SSL is not enabled in this
>   build.",
>       "exception": "MongoDB\Driver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException",
>       "file": "/var/www/html/prodBackend/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php",
>       "line": 87,